# Laravel : I want to order by in another table

Tags: php, laravel

I want to order upload deat at created_at colunm on BookAudio table DESC but now they order by created_at on Book table ASC
result that I get : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wk58.jpg

```
public function viewVerifyAudio()
    {
        $data['books'] = Books::with(['category', 'publisher', 'authors', 'chapter', 'review', 'audio'])
            ->paginate(12);
        $audio['audio'] = BookAudio::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
        return view('admin.view-verify-audio', $data, $audio);
    }
```

Comment: There's no orderBy in the first query()